# In clojure how to transform list of maps to vector of maps?

Tags: list, vector, dictionary, clojure

How to transform a list of maps

```
(def item1 ({:tag1 "val1" ,:tag2 "val2"} {:tag1 "val3" :tag2 "val2"}))
```

to vector of maps. 
The result should be

```
[{:tag1 "val1" ,:tag2 "val2"} {:tag1 "val3" :tag2 "val2"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the [`vec`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/vec) function.

```
(def item1 '({:tag1 "val1" ,:tag2 "val2"} {:tag1 "val3" :tag2 "val2"}))
(vec item1)

;= [{:tag1 "val1", :tag2 "val2"} {:tag1 "val3", :tag2 "val2"}]
```

Note that you were missing a quote on your list of maps, otherwise since maps can take the function position, you are applying the second map to the first one (i.e. `(map key)`).

Comment: Yes, I totally forgot to quote it. Thanks

Comment: `vec` is the specific answer to this question as Juan pointed out, but `(into [] item)` would also work. `into` is more generic, and it's good to keep it in mind for converting (or appending to) collections.